# range sql query result range

Tags: sql-server

```
ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00
```

I want to show result below using ms sql server

```
SALARY
-------------------
0 - 1500 (1)
1500 - 3000(2)
3000 - 4500(1)
4500-6000(0)
6000-7500(0)
7500 - 9000(1)
9000-10500(1)
```

Comment: and what does this have to do with the c# tag. Also what have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is something of a pain, because you want the 0 counts.  Here is one method:

```
with ranges as (
      select 0 as low, 1500 as high union all
      select 1500, 3000 union all
      select 3000, 4500 union all
      . . .
     )
select r.low, r.high, count(t.salary)
from ranges r left join
     t
     on t.salary >= r.low and
        t.salary < r.high
group by r.low, r.high
order by r.low;
```

If you really want, you can use string manipulations to put the range as a single character column.  In general, I prefer to have them as two separate columns.